# a new female aestheticism saw possibilities that liberated them from her legend

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "a new female aestheticism" refer to? I couldn't find any related line in the following this bit.

Feminine novelists had been persuaded that Eliot represented
their highest evolutionary stage, but in the early
twentieth century *a new female aestheticism* saw possibilities
that liberated them from her legend. Dorothy Richardson
discarded Eliot's example simply because she thought
that Eliot wrote "like a man." Most of the feminist novelists,
however, detected a more complicated personality behind
the literature than had the Victorians. Craigie, who
wrote an essay on Eliot for the Encyclopedia Britannica,
saw in the famous intellectual restraint a heroic struggle
rather than a stony indifference.

[A literature of their own](https://books.google.com/books?id=bZOnhRTaspsC&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=%22a%20new%20female%20aestheticism%20saw%20possibilities%20that%20liberated%20them%20from%20her%20legend%22&source=bl&ots=Mu4OEVnONS&sig=ACfU3U3rCvhFais7xnW8649KSBWBKy7SiQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd3qy6-cPtAhVRTxUIHexgCZ8Q6AEwAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20new%20female%20aestheticism%20saw%20possibilities%20that%20liberated%20them%20from%20her%20legend%22&f=false)

Comment: This might be better answered over at [literature.se]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Mitch -  I agree. This is a matter concerning the history of British literature. Quote: " aestheticism [can be divided] into two distinct historical phases, the first of which includes Pre-Raphaelitism and the aesthetic movement, c. 1850–1880, and the second of which includes aestheticism and decadence, c. 1870–1910. https://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780199799558/obo-9780199799558-0002.xml

Comment: Answering this question would involve explanation of the subject matter of this particular text much more than of any general features of English language and usage.

Answer (score -1):

It is poorly written. Aestheticism can't see anything - it doesn't have eyes.

I would be tempted to rewrite it as, "... in the early twentieth century the advent of a new female aestheticism brought about possibilities that liberated them ..."

Have you looked up aestheticism in the dictionary? What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: Metaphorically saying that a [new] perspective, era, or similar "X" ***saw*** something "Y" happen (primarily to indicate concurrence) isn't evidence of poor writing. *The 21st century **has seen** tremendous advances in technology*, for example, is perfectly natural English.

Comment: Yes I have. I don't have an idea what it's that aestheticism is referring to.? Art, writings, women's looks or women's body?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It is in my opinion! In particular, it would be better if the phrase had been, "the advent of a new female aestheticism saw possibilities" which I still find questionable, at least is talking about a time "seeing" something rather than an abstract concept.

Comment: @PurfecrI It's unspecified exactly ***why*** this particular type of aestheticism should be characterised as "female", but I'm sure it won't be anything to do with ***bodily*** differences - just the writer's perception that women in general (George Elliot excepted) think differently to men, so their version[s] of aestheticism are bound to be different.

Comment: In context, even if it *hadn't* been prefaced by ***in the early twentieth century***, I don't see anything wrong with conflating a "school of thought" with the time it came into existence. But I do take the point that "abstract entities" that metaphorically "see" things happen would normally be (directly or indirectly) ***points in time***.